# About whether pycurl supports loading openssl engine

Tags: python, openssl, pycurl, openssl-engine

Hello guys: I would like to ask if python2 can load openssl engine via pycurl? If it supports please how to load it?

I see that there is an SSLENGINE option in pycurl, but by specifying the correct engine path, an error is always reported that the engine file cannot be found

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.